# is it good in react to put a variable as a state value and update it directly

Tags: javascript, reactjs, forms, react-hooks, use-state

now I'm working with react form validation logic

I saw some tutorials on the internet about validating a form in react

and they made a normal variable and put it as a value to a state and update it directly without calling the "set" function provided by react like that

```
let errorsObject = {email: "", password: ""};
const [errors, setErrors] = useState(errorsObject)
```

and they update the variable directly like that

```
const onSubmit = (e) => {
   e.preventDefault();
   if (emailValue === "") {
      errorsObject.email = "please fill in this field"
   }
}
```

now I think this is wrong to update the state value like that I know the the best way to update a state is like that

```
if (emailValue === "") {
      setError({email: "please fill in this field"})
}
```

but there is a problem here

if I updated the state like this it overrides the state last data

and If I tried to get the latest state data like this

```
setErrors((prevState) => {
   return {...prevState, email: "please fill in this field"}
})
```

there is another error

If I submitted the form again and eddited email input data, the last validation data will be stored from the last check!

I hope you understand this, and If there another way to validate a form please tell me

and Thank you all

Comment: The state setters trigger a re-render. If you don't use them, React won't render your changes. What was this _error_ you got when using the [functional update](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#functional-updates).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're right, doing

```
errorsObject.email = "please fill in this field"
```

is definitely a mistake in React - state should not be mutated.

Updating the object's state by doing

```
setErrors((prevState) => {
   return {...prevState, email: "please fill in this field"}
})
```

is the right approach.

> If I submitted the form again and eddited email input data, the last validation data will be stored from the last check!

Reset all of the error properties at the point that the errors get checked - don't update the email property *only* when there's a problem. Since it sounds like you have an email and password, you might want something like:

```
const onSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    setError({
        email: emailValue === '' ? "please fill in this field" : '',
        password: passwordValue === '' ? "please fill in this field" : '',
    });
};
```